# Python Написать программу, которая будет циклом загружать картинки с любого сайта

Tags: python, list, requests

У меня почему то выдает ошибку и не знаю вообще я правильно сделал, не могли бы вы подсказать

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\python\.py", line 21, in <module>
    print((photo.json()))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'
```

```
import requests

photo = requests.get(url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1")

photos_list = photo.json()
for photo in photos_list:
    print((photo.json()))
```

Comment: Какая именно ошибка выходит? **Полный** стек-трейс ошибки разместите прямо в вопросе. Либо сайт вообще не выдаёт `json`, либо в нём не список.

Answer (score 0):

У вас приходит вот такой `json`:

```
{'albumId': 1,
 'id': 1,
 'title': 'accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt',
 'url': 'https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952',
 'thumbnailUrl': 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952'}
```

Это не список, это словарь. Когда вы итерируетесь по словарю, то просто перебираете его ключи, то есть строки. А у строк конечно нет метода `.json()`, поэтому `photo.json()` даёт ошибку.

Чтобы в дальнейшем разбираться больше во всём самому, а не спрашивать по каждой ошибке кого-то просто пробуйте делать `print` каждой сущности, которую получаете в своём коде. Если бы вы напечатали `photos_list` и `photo`, то возможно поняли бы, в чём проблема.

Перебрать значения словаря можно так:

```
for key, val in photos_list.items():
    print(f"{key}: {val}")
```

Comment: а не подскажите что мне нужно сделать чтобы не выводилась ошибка пожалуйста

Comment: Я добавил код, который будет работать